# How To Switch Branches With Changes Made In A Folder That Was Added To .gitignore?

Tags: git

I created a branch temp.
I installed a newer version of the express module. I added node_modules folder to .gitignore.

```
[ubuntu@ip-172-31-10-215:~/bitstarter]$git checkout master
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
        node_modules/.bin/express
        node_modules/express/.npmignore
        node_modules/express/History.md
        node_modules/express/LICENSE
        node_modules/express/Makefile
        node_modules/express/Readme.md
        node_modules/express/bin/express
        node_modules/express/index.js
        node_modules/express/lib/express.js
        node_modules/express/lib/request.js
        node_modules/express/lib/response.js
        node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js
        node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js
        node_modules/express/lib/utils.js
        node_modules/express/lib/view.js
        node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/.npmignore
        node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/LICENSE
        node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/index.js
        node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/cache.js
        node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/connect.js
        node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/index.js
        node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/basicAuth.js
        node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/bodyParser.js
        node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/compress.js
        node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/cookieParser.js
        node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/csrf.js
        node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/directory.js
        node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/errorHandler.js
        node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/favicon.js
        node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/limit.js
        node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/logger.js
        node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/methodOverride.js
        node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/query.js
        node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/responseTime.js
        node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/session.js
        node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/session/cookie.js
        node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/session/memory.js
        node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/session/session.js
        node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/session/store.js
        node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/static.js
        node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/staticCache.js
        node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/vhost.js
        node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/patch.js
        node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/public/directory.html
        node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/public/error.html
        node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/public/favicon.ico
        node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/public/icons/page.png
        node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/public/icons/page_add.png
        node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/public/icons/page_attach.png
        node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/public/icons/page_code.png
        node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/public/icons/page_copy.png
        node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/public/icons/page_delete.png
        node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/public/icons/page_edit.png
        node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/public/icons/page_error.png
        node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/public/icons/page_excel.png
        node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/public/icons/page_find.png
        node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/public/icons/page_gear.png
        node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/public/icons/page_go.png
        node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/public/icons/page_green.png
        node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/public/icons/page_key.png
        node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/public/icons/page_lightning.png
        node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/public/icons/page_link.png
        node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/public/icons/page_paintbrush.png
        node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/public/icons/page_paste.png
        node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/public/icons/page_red.png
        nod
Aborting
```

Here is git status (for fun):

```
[ubuntu@ip-172-31-10-215:~/bitstarter]$git status
# On branch temp
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

It is 1:30 at night here so I'm dead tired and I just cannot for the life of me find a clean solution (scared about losing my work or messing up dependencies or something).
 I will check answers tomorrow thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you've already committed those files before you added the rule to `.gitignore`.

You can remove them from Git with `git rm --cached <file>`.

In order to switch branches with a dirty directory, generally the fastest and easiest is to `stash` the changes.

Comment: You are right... if I recall I think I did.
I did npm install. Then I committed. Then I added to .gitignore. Then I committed. Ugh, too lazy to look up stash right now. Will do so tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

If you have just installed the new version and the previous files were already tracked by git, you can untrack files which have been added to git.

```
git rm --cached filename
```

Git will stop tracking these files and now add that folder to .gitignore.